# WebSocket connection timing out

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I'm writing a WebSocket connection between a JavaScript client and node.JS server.

My client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Socket Test</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.in:26031/');
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        ws.send('Hi this is web client.');
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
    };
</script>
```

Server code:

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    socket.write('SERVER: Hello! This is server speaking.\n');
    socket.end('SERVER: Closing connection now.\n');
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
server.listen(26031, () => {
    console.log('opened server on', server.address().port);
});
```

The error i'm Getting:
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.in:26031/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I tried other answers in stack overflow, but everything seems perfect from my side. The server port is open for accepting request. What else might be wrong?

Comment: I think websocket in backend not defined correctly by you.
Please check this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Answer (score 1):

Use "wss://" only when you have SSL install
Or else try with ws://

You can also try using Socket.IO for socket connection.

Comment: Yes, I do have SSL

Comment: You need to define ssl certificates in your nodeJS web socket server. I hope this will help you http://blog.zackad.com/en/2017/08/19/create-websocket-with-nodejs.html